# How to delete HSTORE keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, migration

I have the following migration:

```
class CreateFoos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :foos do |t|
      t.hstore :foos_properties
    end
  end
end
```

In the hstore column, I have 2 keys: `:foo` and `:bar`. Is it possible to create another migration to remove `:foo`? How should it look like?

I've found this:

```
Foo.update_all([%(foos_properties = delete("foos_properties",?)), 'foo'])
```

Is that safe? Or should I consider a more sensible approach?

Comment: you can changes your keys like you want without migration.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is fine. I do something slightly similar:

```
ObjectModel.find_each do |object_model|
  object_model.foos_properties.delete("foo")
end
```

Comment: I think you need to add `object_model.save` to update it in database level.